# Help in defining a certain equivalence relation

Tags: definition, relations, equivalence-relations

Let S be the set of sequences of the form $[a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]$, where the $a_i$'s are complex numbers and $n\in \mathbb N$. For $x,y \in S$, we say that $x$ is a repetition of $y$ if $x$ is formed by putting a number of $y$'s side by side: for example, $[1,2,3,1,2,3]$ is a repetition of $[1,2,3]$, and $[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]$ is a repetition of both $[1,2,1,2]$ and $[1,2]$.

Given any $x \in S$, let Sub(x) $= \{ \text{ }y \in S \text{ } |\text{ }x \text{ extends } y \}$.

Define the following relation ~:

Given $x,y \in S$, $x\text{~}y$ if the sequence of least length in Sub(x) is a cyclic permutation of the sequence of least lenght in Sub(y).

For example, $[1,2,3,1,2,3] \text{~} [2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]$.

It can easily be seen that ~ is an equivalence relation on S.

My question is: Could I make this definition less wordy? Also, how could I make "x is a repetition of y" more rigorous? And is there a well-established name for S?

Comment: By '$x$ extends $y$' do you mean that $x$ is a repetition of $y$, or simply that $y$ is the initial segment of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the set of possible values doesn't seem to play any role here, let it be $C$.

So, $S=\bigcup_nC^n$, and let $Z:=C^{\Bbb Z}=\{(c_k)_{k\in\Bbb Z}\}$ be the set of 2-way infinite sequences. 
Now consider the map $f:S\to Z$ which periodically repeats the input sequence in both directions, i.e.,
$$f((a_0,\dots, a_{n-1})):=\ k\mapsto a_{k\mathop{mod}n}$$
And take the equivalence relation '*shifted version of*', $R$ on $Z$, such that $\ (a_k)\,R\, (b_k)$ iff $\exists u\in\Bbb Z:\ \forall k\, (b_k=a_{k+u})$.

Then, for $x, y\in S$ we have $x\sim y\ \iff\ f(x)\, R\, f(y)$.

I'm not aware of any particular name for it, but we can calmly call the quotient set $S/\sim$ the set of (finite) **cycles** of elements of $C$.